# node.js sometimes have problem with link scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

Hello i create SPA client side - here all work correctly (using vanilla-router)

But server node.js sometimes give me error when try load linked script

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Error appear only when i use more than one backslash in url (/).

for example

> localhost:3000 - is okay (script loaded)
>
> localhost:3000/test - is okay
>
> localhost:3000/about - is okay
>
> localhost:3000/test/test - Error
>
> localhost:3000/profile/user - Error

My server code

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
```

in dist folder i have test.js script

my code from index.html

```
<script src="test.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `<script src="test.js" ></script>` in your frontend, it will try to fetch from the "current folder", so if you are on the page `localhost:3000/test/test` it will try to load `localhost:3000/test/test.js` which means your backend will be looking for `dist/test/test.js`, which likely does not exist, thus leading it to load your index page instead (giving you the error message about the unexpected `<`).

Change your frontend to use:

`<script src="/test.js" ></script>`

Notice the added slash in front, which means it will try to load from the root, i.e. no matter which page you are on in the frontend, it will load `localhost:3000/test.js`